# How to enable "update-all packages" button at nuget interface?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

Is there a way to enable "Update All" button at this nuget screen?

Although we can do it via Package Manager Console, I'm pretty sure that I've seen this button before...

Answer (score 1):

There is the `Update All` button available and enabled in the updates section of the Nuget GUI, as seen in the following screenshot:

[image]